# OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - undefined EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, javabeans

In order to overcome LazyInitializationException I've decided to use OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - here's code from my AppInitializer class which implements WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    registerListener(servletContext);
    registerDipsatcherServlet(servletContext);
    registerOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(servletContext);
}

private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
}

private void registerDipsatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfiguration.class);
    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
    customizeRegistration(dispatcher);
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

private void registerOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInView", new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
    registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD), false, "/*");
}

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

And here's the @Configuration class which defines the bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager", basePackages = "podraza.piotr.eshopper.repository")
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Value("${jpa.show-sql:false}")
    private boolean showSql;  

    @Value("${jpa.datasource.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${jpa.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jpa.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${jpa.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    /*
    @Value("${jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String hibernateDdlAuto;
    */

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(showSql);
        //hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateDdlAuto);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(databaseUrl, username, password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("podraza.piotr.eshopper.entity");
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("defaultPersistenceUnit");
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

}
```

How can I indicate this bean for the filter?

Comment: That `@Configuration` class is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` or `ContextLoaderListener`?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I determine that?

Comment: Your `AppInitializer` should also construct both the `ContextLoaderListener` and/or `DispatcherServlet` which loads configuration. Ideally you would extend the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and configure which classes get loaded by which (saves you some lines of code :) ).

Comment: It does construct both. I've posted full code.

Comment: Why on earth do you have this contraption? You are extending a class and destroy its functionality by implementing everything yourself? Either the class isn't loaded or loaded only by the `DispatcherServlet` which makes it undetectable for the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` as that requires the entitymangerfactory to be available in the root context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Spring classes and the first thing you do is not use it. Replace your `AppInitializer` with the following.

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
      registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] {PersistenceConfiguration.class}
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      throw new Class[] {MvcConfiguration.class};
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
  }

  protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return return new Filter[] {new OpenentityManagerInViewFilter()};
  }

}
```

Also make sure that in your `MvcConfiguration` you aren't loading the `PersistenceConfiguration` class again as that would lead to bean duplication.

Comment: After doing that problem with undefined EntityManagerFactory is gone but I still have problem with lazily initialization and PersistenceConfiguration couldn't resolve my properties.

Comment: Because 1, you are loading your configuration twice, resulting in 2 entity manager factories, one opening a session with the database which is useless because the second one is actually going to be used. 2. You haven't defined a `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` in your configuration so your `@Value` is never going to be replaced.

Comment: I have defined PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer in WebMvcConfiguration and my @Value's used to working properly. How I am I loading configuration twice? I'm confused right now ;-)

Comment: Once by the `ContextLoaderLIstener` and, I guess due to a `@ComponentScan` again in the `DispatcherServlet`. The one in the CLL is used by the filter (without replaced values) and the one in the DS is used by everything else. Ideally your services, repositories, infrastructure beans (datasource, entity manager, connection factories) should be loaded by the CLL and only the web related things by the DS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm going to expand my knowledge in that area as I see there's a quite few thing that I might have omitted as I've just started my adventure with Spring ;-) Don't want to trouble you more but if I ever encounter such problem is there a way to contact you other than Stack? Thanks again, you've been very helpful.

Comment: Thanks to your guidance I've managed to overcome this problem and everything is working well now. Once again, thank you.